# Permission issues with elastic beanstalk deployment via git aws.push and IAM user

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have an existing eb application+environment that can be deployed just fine by uploading a zip archive. To shorten the development/test cycle, I want to use `git aws.push` on my existing local repository for deployment.

I created an IAM user and followed the 3-step instruction here [AWS Elastic Beanstalk - Using eb to attach git repo to existing EB environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14207203/aws-elastic-beanstalk-using-eb-to-attach-git-repo-to-existing-eb-environment) by @aldrinleal. These are the 3 steps

1. Install DevTools
2. Run the repository setup
3. git aws.config

All 3 steps seems to proceed just fine. I entered the security credential of my new IAM user as well as the application+environment names of my eb setup.

It's `git aws.push` that gave me a ton of troubles. What followed was a series of permission errors that essentially means the IAM user I've created does not have permission to perform actions like `cloudformation:GetTemplate, elasticbeanstalk:CreateStorageLocation, elasticbeanstalk:CreateApplicationVersion, ec2:DescribeImages, s3:CreateBucket` and many more.

I find myself having to run `git aws.push`, receive a permission error, then update the IAM permissions and try again. This can't possibly be the right way to deploy on elastic beanstalk via git. I'm new to aws and feel a bit overwhelmed with so many things to learn at the moment. Can someone shed some lights on this `git aws.push` situation to help me get passed this so I can do further experimentation and learning?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you should use an existing IAM Policy instead of trying to build up a Policy as you run into issues.

To do this, go to the [IAM Console](https://console.aws.amazon.com/iam/home) and then go to the user that you are using.

Click on the User and then you'll see all the info relating to that User. Now go to "Attach User Policy". It'll bring up a window that lets you select a Policy Template, use the Policy Generator, or set a Custom Policy.

We're just going to use the Policy Template feature. Next scroll in the list until you find "AWS Elastic Beanstalk" in the list. There will be two templates:

- AWS Elastic Beanstalk Full Access
- AWS Elastic Beanstalk Read Only Access

Each has a description so you can read that for each. Basically the Full Access template is what you will want for using the `eb` cli which provides `git aws.push`.

Select it and then click "Apply Policy".

Try running `git aws.push` again and you *shouldn't* have issues if you have everything configured properly to use that user.

Comment: Shhweet! Thanks, you're a life saver and I feel like an idiot just given an uh-duh moment. When I added the policy for that user group, I picked "Power User" thinking that it would trump everything else except admin. After your answer and reading the actual text policy for "Elastic Beanstalk Full Access", things now make a lot of sense. Thank you!

Comment: No problem! I'm glad I could help. I totally understand that feeling of being overwhelmed especially with all that AWS has. You just have to learn one thing at a time and things start to make sense and the underlying design starts to get pieced together.